# How can I show the plus and minus signs for nodes with children?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I use this code for adding child nodes to a selected node:

```
private void PopulateSubNodes(DataTable Dt, TreeNode RootNode)
{
    RootNode.Nodes.Clear();
    TreeNode Node;
    foreach (DataRow Dr in Dt.Rows)
    {
        if (int.Parse(Dr[2].ToString()) > 0)
        {
            Node = RootNode.Nodes.Add(Dr[1] + " , " + Dr[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            Node = RootNode.Nodes.Add(Dr[1].ToString());
        }
        Node.Tag = Dr[0];
    }
    RootNode.Expand();
}
```

I know Id, Title and child count of the node.

In Dr[2], I check the child count for each child, if it is bigger than 0, I want to show plus and minus for this node, else I don't want to.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you logically know there are children, but they have not yet been added to the tree, you will need to add a node.

The easiest way is to use a Placeholder Node when you detect this, and remove it when the node is expanded.

```
internal class EmptyTreeNode : TreeNode { }

private void PopulateSubModes(...)
{
    // ...

    if (hasChildren) node.Nodes.Add(new EmptyTreeNode());

    // ...
}

private static void TreeView1OnBeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs args)
{
    // If this isn't one of our special nodes... abort.
    if (args.Node.Nodes.Count == 0 || !(args.Node.Nodes[0] is EmptyTreeNode))
        return;

    args.Node.Nodes.Clear();

    // -- Do whatever to REALLY populate it
    args.Node.Nodes.Add( new TreeNode( "Weeeeeeeee" ) );
    args.Node.Nodes.Add( new TreeNode( "Hooooooah!" ) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if the node does not have child nodes , the +/- sign will not show

make sure that the leaf node does not have an empty child node if it still showing the +/- sign.